# Setting private set fields from a post request on backend server

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am making my way through various todo list tutorials while learning react and entity framework. As some background I have made my way though [Microsoft's todo list todo tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.2&tabs=visual-studio); although I have replaced the front end part of that with my own front end. It was all working fine, until I've tried to extend it and hit the issue I will outline below.

I have updated the EF model to include private set fields for the added benefits (becoming read only after it is initialised etc). This is shown in the code below.

```
public class TodoItem
{
    public long id { get; private set; }
    public string title { get; private set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; private set; }

    // Define constructor
    public TodoItem(long newId, string newTitle)
    {
        id = newId;
        title = newTitle;
        IsComplete = false;
    }

    public void ToggleComplete()
    {
        IsComplete = !IsComplete;
    }
}
```

The post action from the controller is shown below. I have included some debug printouts as these show where the field is already showing the title as null. 
I believe this is the section of code I am struggling with and would like to know what mistakes I am making or what the best practices are!

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> PostTodoItem(TodoItem item)
    {

        // returns null if model field set to private
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("item title: " + item.title); 

        // Create new item passing in arguments for constructor
        TodoItem newItem = new TodoItem(item.id, item.title);

        _context.TodoItems.Add(newItem);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetTodoItem), new { id = newItem.id }, newItem);
    }
```

The frontend method (js) where the post request is made is shown below:

```
const addTodoMethod = (title) => {   
// Create new item
const item = {
  title: title,
  id: Date.now(),
  isComplete: false,
}

// Update state
const newTodos = [...todos, item];
setTodos(newTodos);

// Can use POST requiest to add to db
axios.post('https://localhost:44371/api/todo/',
            item)
  .then(res=> {
    console.log("Added item. Title: ", title);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
})}
```

I hope I've explained the problem well enough. Let me know if there is anything else needed!

Answer (score 1):

> I have updated the EF model to include private set fields for the added benefits (becoming read only after it is initialised etc).

There are two problems in what you did. The first one is that the Models must have a parameter-less constructor, and the second one that the properties must be public, both getter and setter.

The best you can do right now is to stop using your database entity for user input and create a ViewModel class:

```
public class TodoItemViewModel
{
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public bool IsComplete { get; set; }
}

public async Task<ActionResult<TodoItem>> PostTodoItem(TodoItemViewModel model)
{
    var item = new TodoItem(item.id, item.title); 
    ...
}
```